# if then else in ocamlyacc

Tags: ocaml, yacc, ocamlyacc

Can anyone brief how can I implement if then else in Ocamlyacc. I've defined tokens from lexical analyzer(ocamllex) namely IF, THEN, ELSE. For the if statement, I have defined tokens: GREATERTHAN, LESSERTHAN, EQUALTO for integers. I've searched many tutorials but to no avail!

UPDATE:

I want to interpret the result and return the value of the expression dictated by the if-else statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define rules :

```
ifthenelse :    
 |   IF condition THEN statement ELSE statement   { IfThenElse($1,$2,$3) }


condition :    
| INT EQUALTO INT  { Cond(EqualTo,$1,$3) }   
| INT LESSERTHAN INT {  Cond(LesserThan,$1,$3) }   
| INT GREATERTHAN INT {  Cond(GeaterThan,$1,$3) }
```

Don't forget to define regular expression for int, in your lex fil

Comment: Could you also define the functions IfThenElse , Cond for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just a type you define : Cond of op * int * int etc.

Comment: Can I use Ocaml to evaluate this - like an interpreter?

Comment: You can very easily write an interpreter for your abstract syntax, but it doesn't come free.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield: I suppose that will require me to write a function that takes input from ocamlyacc and executes the required action.

Comment: This sounds right. The function would consume the output of the parser and evaluate it. It sounds complicated but once you start coding it's a breeze (in my experience).

Comment: You can see a simple example here (there's a make top for top level playing) https://github.com/ontologiae/DRS-Analysis-Tool

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've seen it, but the OCaml manual gives a complete ocamllex/ocamlyacc example that calculates the values of expressions: [Desk Calculator Example](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual026.html#htoc156).

The example shows that you can calculate your result in the ocamlyacc actions if you want to. For a simple example, it's not at all hard to follow. In a more realistic case, you would probably want to construct an abstract syntax tree for later processing (such as evaluation). The code has a similar flavor except that the cases are given by the different constructors of your AST type rather than by the different grammar rules.